# What is a Federated Configuration?

Tags: rabbitmq, federated

I am confused at this sentence found on the RabbitMQ site, Google wasn't much help: https://www.rabbitmq.com/

"RabbitMQ can be deployed in distributed and federated configurations to meet high-scale, high-availability requirements."

What does it mean when a service can be deployed in a distributed and federated configuration? What is a distributed configuration? What is a federated configuration?

Thanks,

---- UPDATE ----

Upon looking at the tags, I saw "Federated processing is a delegation of method invocation calls to a trusted third party APIs or web services." Related?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A federated configuration is a configuration in which resources belong to different organizational entities (ex. departments, companies, etc.).

A distributed configuration is a configuration in which resources are not in the same location, but all belong to the same organizational entity.

Obviously, it is also possible to have a configuration that is both federated and distributed.

https://www.progress.com/blogs/distributed-vs-federated